Some confusion about the tensor product over $\mathbb Z[G]$
Let $G$ be an arbitrary group. There are many ways to form $G$-module
structure.

If $A$ and $B$ are left $G$-modules, we have a natural $G$-action on $A\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}B$, i.e. $g.(a\otimes b):=(ga)\otimes(gb)$ for $a\in A, b\in B$ and $g\in G$.

If $A$ and $B$ are left $G$-modules, we can make $A$ into a right module by putting $a.g:=g^{-1}a$, for $a\in A, g\in G$. Then we form the tensor product $A\otimes_{G}B$. We have isomorphism $A\otimes_{G}B\cong (A\otimes_{\mathbb Z}B)_{G}$, where the lower script denotes the co-variant. This isomorphism is of abelian groups, and is of $G$-modules if we put trivial $G$-action on $A\otimes_{G} B$ (So when we talk about $A\otimes_G B$, do we usually mean a trivial $G$-module?).


Now, let's put $A$ to be something with natural $G$-bimodule structures, where I feel extremely confused. Let $B$ denote some $G$-module.
For example, put $A:=\mathbb Z[G]$. Since we have the canonical isomorphism $\mathbb Z[G]\otimes_{G} B\cong B$, it seems that we do not adapt the second construction above (otherwise we have $g\otimes b=1\otimes g^{-1}b) $and we just let $G$ act on the first factor.
Another example, see page 107 of Algebraic Number Theory by Cassel's & Frohlich:
when showing the uniqueness of cup products, the authors tensor the exact sequence of $G$-modules
$$
0\to A'\to A_*=\mathbb Z[G]\otimes_\mathbb Z A\to A\to 0
$$
with any $G$-module $B$ over $\mathbb Z$, and they say that
$$
A_*\otimes B=\mathbb Z[G]\otimes A\otimes B=(A\otimes B)_*.
$$
I was taught by my professor that, to be compatible with definitions,
the equality is in fact realized by an isomorphism:
$$
s\otimes  a_s\otimes b\mapsto s\otimes a_s\otimes(s^{-1})b.
$$
Through the examples, it seem that the followings are true.
1.When $A$ has natural left and right $G$-module structures, we do not regard $A\otimes_G B$ a trivial $G$-module, instead we let $G$ act on the first factor;
2.When tensoring over $\mathbb Z$, we usually let $G$ act diagonally, unless we consider induced modules, in which case we only let $G$ act on $\mathbb Z[G]$ from left side;
So are there any example when we use the second $G$-module structure, which makes artificially a left module into a right module? I am convinced that Cassel's & Frohlich's book does, for example( as I think), in page 98, when the authors explain the connecting homomorphism $\delta: H_1(G,C)\to H_0(G,A)$ of homology, w.r.t. the
short exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$. There, they write an element of $Z_1(G,C)$ as the class represented by a function $f: C\to C$ and it is computed that $df=\sum_{s\in G}(s^{-1}-1)f(s)=0$. I think here there won't be the mysterious "inverse" of $s$ unless
they do not adapt the natural right $G$-module structure on $G$.
Thanks in advance for anyone clarifying my confusion.

When $A$ is already a right module, one would have $a.g\otimes_{G} b= a \otimes_{G} g.b$. The inverse appears when turning a left module structure to a right one. However, the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ is already a bimodule, it has both a left and a right action corresponding to left and right group multiplication. There are no inverses, the tensor product involves the right multiplication.

@MPos Thank you for your answer. But how about the computation of $\delta: H_1\to H_0$? I think another way to make the $s^{-1}$ reasonable is to consider the function $f$ as $s\mapsto c_{s^{-1}}$ for $f$ corresponding to $\sum_{s\in G}1\otimes s\otimes c_s$, which uses the same logic as setting the isomorphism between induced and conduced modules. But it seems that, as  I know, the isomorphism is only true for finite groups...
